# Youtube video in UIWebView takes ages to load

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

I’m trying to open Youtube video URLs in a UIWebView and for some reason it takes ages for the pages to appear.

Now, the weird thing is, that every other page I open in the UIWebView, works like a charm and loads pretty much instantly. For example, open some Youtube channel page, I get the page in mere seconds. But opening a direct link to a video in some cases takes like 4 minutes. It doesn’t fail to load, but it seems to take a really long time. When it is open, it works fine – the video plays and everything.

Anyone might have a clue what’s causing this? I’ve read all the other threads and the same circumstances do not apply, as I’m not embedding the videos, I’m just opening a URL in the UIWebView.

There’s this in the console:

warning: No copy of QuickTime Plugin.webplugin/QuickTime Plugin found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

But that seems to appear even when I open a YouTube channel page and that comes up instantly and appears only once.

I’m using both the simulator and the device and the problem is evident in both.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem, and can't figure it out

Comment: No, but for some reason the same videos are now working find and it seems that the problem was maybe on youtube’s side. No idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens when you try to open lengthy videos. Can you test your app with videos of different length's (resolution).
My guess is, Mediaplayer tries to fetch (buffer) part (or complete?) video upfront and hence this behavior.
If this is the reason for delay, I doubt if there is hardly anything that can be done (other than showing inferior quality youtube link (if exists)).

Comment: Nope, I tried this already. I had the same idea at first, but acted the same with both 1 second and 10 minute movies.